# How to use to_char function functionality in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, oracle, mysql-workbench, sqlyog

I have a table `tine_by_day` and I know how to use `TO_CHAR` function in `oracle`, but how to get same output if I use in `MySQL`?

Is there any conversion function in `MySQL` for `TO_CHAR()`?

I have already tried `date_format` instead `to_char` but I'm not getting sufficient results.

```
SELECT
    to_char(t.the_date,'mm-DD-YYYY') Date,
    SUM(sf7.unit_sales) UnitSales,
    SUM(sf7.store_sales) StoreSales,
    SUM(sf7.store_cost) StoreCost
FROM time_by_day t INNER JOIN sales_fact_1997 sf7 ON t.time_id=sf7.time_id
WHERE
    to_char(t.the_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')>='2012-01-01'
    AND
    to_char(t.the_date,'YYYY-MM-DD')<='2012-01-07'
GROUP BY t.the_date
ORDER BY t.the_date
```

Comment: _write a Query in SQL_ ? Sorry I don't get it!

Comment: i m using same query in oracle that to_char function working fine or i am getting out put proper but if i m using sql then i m getting error because that to_char function is not supported by sql ..so i m looking same kind of function for sql ..

Comment: I edited your Question, Please tag the question appropriately. Because the answers depend on it.

Comment: thanx a lot Maheswaran...:)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In SQL Server, you would typically use the `convert()` function, which is not nearly as convenient as `to_char()`.  For your query, you only need it in the `select` clause:

```
SELECT convert(varchar(10), t.the_date, 110) as Date,
       SUM(sf7.unit_sales) as UnitSales,
       SUM(sf7.store_sales) as StoreSales,
       SUM(sf7.store_cost) as StoreCost
FROM time_by_day t INNER JOIN
     sales_fact_1997 sf7
     ON t.time_id = sf7.time_id
WHERE t.the_date >='2012-01-01' AND
      t.the_date <= '2012-01-07'
GROUP BY t.the_date
ORDER BY t.the_date;
```

SQL Server will *normally* treat the ISO standard YYYY-MM-DD as a date and do the conversion automatically.  There is a particular internationalization setting that treats this as YYYY-DD-MM, alas.  The following should be interpreted correctly, regardless of such settings (although I would use the above form):

```
WHERE t.the_date >= cast('20120101' as date) AND
      t.the_date <= cast('20120107' as date)
```

EDIT:

In MySQL, you would just use `date_format()`:

```
SELECT date_format(t.the_date, '%m-%d-%Y') as Date,
       SUM(sf7.unit_sales) as UnitSales,
       SUM(sf7.store_sales) as StoreSales,
       SUM(sf7.store_cost) as StoreCost
FROM time_by_day t INNER JOIN
     sales_fact_1997 sf7
     ON t.time_id = sf7.time_id
WHERE t.the_date >= date('2012-01-01') AND
      t.the_date <= date('2012-01-07')
GROUP BY t.the_date
ORDER BY t.the_date;
```

Comment: It sort of does.  The only format that always works doesn't have hyphens, but I stick with the form with hyphens.  In addition to my being a human being (and finding it more readable), this form is widely accepted across databases, even in Oracle using the `date` keyword.

Comment: Got it Gordon.! Your update clarified me and the comments better n better!

Comment: Thanx for your suitable response i m using only mysql

Answer (score 0):

Based on Gordons approach, but usign CHAR(10) instead of VARCHAR(10) since there's hardly a date not being returned with a length of 10...

```
SELECT convert(char(10), t.the_date, 110) as [Date],
   SUM(sf7.unit_sales) as UnitSales,
   SUM(sf7.store_sales) as StoreSales,
   SUM(sf7.store_cost) as StoreCost
FROM time_by_day t INNER JOIN
 sales_fact_1997 sf7
 ON t.time_id = sf7.time_id
WHERE t. the_date >='20120101' AND
  t.the_date <= '20120107'
GROUP BY t.the_date
ORDER BY t.the_date;
```

Edit: also changed the date format in the WHERE clause to be ISO compliant and therewith not affected by the setting of DATEFORMAT.

Comment: Thanx for your suitable response but i m not using sql server .i m using only mysql

Comment: @sam140 still.. only sql means? Is sql a name for DBMS?

Answer (score 0):

Recommend you do this :

```
CAST($(STR) AS CHAR(40))
```